# How to recognize stream entry?

Tags: personal-practice, theravada, stages-of-the-path

Have disappeared the body and thoughts,there is remaining awareness with the knows during practice.what is this stage of practice?how to know whtere this is stream entry?

Answer (score 5):

Stream-entry is to have verified confidence in the Dhamma, which is seen here & now, timeless, inviting verification, pertinent, to be realized by the wise for themselves.

What this means is to fully realise the abandoning of craving, attachment & self-view brings peace (and the opposite brings suffering & disturbance).

Answer (score 0):

> Then Anathapindika the householder, surrounded by about 500 lay followers, went to the Blessed One and, on arrival, having bowed down to him, sat to one side. So the Blessed One said to Ven. Sariputta: "Sariputta, when you know of a householder clothed in white, that he is restrained in terms of the five training rules and that he obtains at will, without difficulty, without hardship, four pleasant mental abidings in the here & now, then if he wants he may state about himself: 'Hell is ended; animal wombs are ended; the state of the hungry shades is ended; states of deprivation, destitution, the bad bourns are ended! I am a stream-winner, steadfast, never again destined for states of woe, headed for self-awakening!'
>
> "Now, in terms of which five training rules is he restrained?
>
> ...
>
> "And which four pleasant mental abidings in the here & now does he obtain at will, without difficulty, without hardship?
>
> ...
>
> "Sariputta, when you know of a householder clothed in white, that he is restrained in terms of the five training rules and that he obtains at will, without difficulty, without hardship, four pleasant mental abidings in the here & now, then if he wants he may state about himself: 'Hell is ended; animal wombs are ended; the state of the hungry shades is ended; states of deprivation, destitution, the bad bourns are ended! I am a stream-winner, steadfast, never again destined for states of woe, headed for self-awakening!'
>
> ...
>
> [The Householder](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.179.than_en.html)

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*